# Is it possible to launch a 64 bit command line from a 32 bit application?

Tags: command-line, 64-bit

Anyone know if it's possible to launch a 64 bit command line from a 32 bit application?

We have to copy our applicationHost.config file into C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\ using a 32 bit process but it would be nice if the batch file that does that could take care of making that happen so we could launch it from a 32 bit program like VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want to access the "real" System32 directory, normally visible from 64-bit processes only, from a 32-bit process?

To do that just use "sysnative" instead of "system32" from the 32-bit process, e.g.:

%Windir%\Sysnative\Inetsrv...